# SQL Server 2016 - “Always on” issue on secondary server , redo thread blocked

Tags: sql-server-2016

I need help for an always-on issue after upgrading to 2016 from 2014. Redo thread is causing blocking for all the select query on the secondary replica. all long running select queries are getting blocked by redo thread for a specific database. All DBs are already in sync. redo thread is getting blocked once I am running SQL job to fetch the data from secondary database.. redo queue size is also 0 and DB also synchronized before running the job. read routing URL also configured. Has anyone faced such a scenario? Please help with this.

I have tried multiple things to rid of deadlock issue and enabled the Is_Read_Commited_Snapshot option as well but still, that REDO thread ( DB sync) is blocked.

Comment: Welcome to SE!, please share the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, this issue could be due to the **multi-threading model** or **parallelism**.

Until **SQL Server 2016**, the `transaction log redo was handled by single redo thread` for each database, this model is called as **serial redo**.

Starting from **SQL Server 2016**, the default redo model is **parallel redo**. It provides **multiple threads for transactions** and **additional worker threads for dirty page flush IO operations**.

While working with the **concurrent** workload, **`DIRTY_PAGE_TABLE_LOCK`** waits are generated frequently by the worker thread, and at the same time, query threads will try to access the tables, this will cause the **performance issues on both SELECT query and redo operations**.

This issue was fixed on the `latest Cummulative Update` - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4135048/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2016-sp2

As a **workaround**, you can **disable the parallel redo model** and **enable the serial redo** by enabling the **trace flag 3459.**

I hope this helps! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will try with this solution and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for giving the work around, i have applied it and it resolved REDO thread blocking issue on secondary server.

Comment: @user181726, Welcome, if it resolve the issue, kindly accept the solution and close it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, This is resolved my issue. How to accept and close it.

Comment: There is tick mark, left side of the answer, up sign for answer useful, down sign for answer not useful and tick mark for answer solved your problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have accepted the answer

Comment: Hello Ratish, After getting enable the trace flag 3459  , my transaction log backup is large around 1 GB on primary replica and it is  configured in every 15 minutes.Is this trace causing Tlog backup larger or some other thing is causing T log backup file size larger than usual. Please suggest

Comment: If there is a huge number of transactions executed in 15 mins, there is a chance. To  understand more about this, refer this page: https://serverfault.com/a/298290/355547,  I am checking on enabling flag 3459.